# How to remove this error in C# with framework 3.5 this error come Default parameter specifiers are not permitted

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

//This is a piece of code for the transformation of sql to excel output:

```
class Program    
{  
    public static void WriteToFile(DataTable dataSource, string fileOutputPath, bool firstRowIsColumnHeader = false, string seperator = ";") 
    {            
        var sw = new StreamWriter(fileOutputPath, false);
        int icolcount = dataSource.Columns.Count;
        if (!firstRowIsColumnHeader)
        {                
            for (int i = 0; i < icolcount; i++)
            {                    
                sw.Write(dataSource.Columns[i]);                  
                if (i < icolcount - 1)
                    sw.Write(seperator); 
            }                
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: You can't have parameter defaults in .net framework 3.5.  Those weren't added until 4.0.

Comment: Ya I know, but how can I do that in framwork 3.5 if I need to remove this error.

Comment: @SaurabhKhurana, define to method overloads one with default parameter and one without. *The old way*

Comment: I cant change because this is the latest famework I have

Comment: I could not do that.. can u provide me solution, I did lots of brainstorm

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your problem is: if you can't use default parameters - don't use them. Do you have problem passing arguments to a function? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just write method overloads. Start from minimum argument, and write one overload for each argument you want to add.

```
public static void WriteToFile(DataTable dataSource, string fileOutputPath) 
{
    WriteToFile(dataSource, fileOutputPath, false);    
}

public static void WriteToFile(DataTable dataSource, string fileOutputPath, bool firstRowIsColumnHeader) 
{ 
    WriteToFile(dataSource, fileOutputPath, firstRowIsColumnHeader, ";");          
}

public static void WriteToFile(DataTable dataSource, string fileOutputPath, bool firstRowIsColumnHeader, string seperator) 
{ 
    // do stuff           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do exactly that in C# 3.0 (that comes with VS 2008), but you can use overloads that will works the same for some ways that you can use default parameters:

```
class Program {

  public static void WriteToFile(DataTable dataSource, string fileOutputPath, bool firstRowIsColumnHeader, string seperator) {
    ...code here
  }

  public static void WriteToFile(DataTable dataSource, string fileOutputPath, bool firstRowIsColumnHeader) {
    WriteToFile(dataSource, fileOutputPath, firstRowIsColumnHeader, ";");
  }
  public static void WriteToFile(DataTable dataSource, string fileOutputPath) {
    WriteToFile(dataSource, fileOutputPath, false, ";");
  }

}
```

Example of usage that works:

```
WriteToFile(source, path);
WriteToFile(source, path, true);
WriteToFile(source, path, true, ",");
```

Example of usage that doesn't work in C# 3.0 that works in 4.0:

```
WriteToFile(source, path, seperator: ",");
```

Comment: @Habib: Yes, you are right, I have clarified the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**It is a feature of C# language and not related to .Net framework 4.0.** If you want to use .Net framework 3.5 and use default parameter, then use Visual studio 2010 or above.

These uses C# compilers 4.0 or higher and you will be able to compile it with .Net framework 3.5.

You may see the article by Jon Skeet: [Untangling the Versions](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter1/versions.aspx)

First picture showing a project in .Net framework 3.5

[image]

Second picture showing optional parameter

[image]

Comment: Yes, that can be done if we have visual studio 2010 but I am working on visual 2008 . It wont work. Thanks for your effort, you are right in this sense too.

Answer (score 0):

Use overloads...

```
class Program    {  
     public static void WriteToFile(DataTable dataSource, string fileOutputPath, bool firstRowIsColumnHeader, string seperator)   
     {            
        var sw = new StreamWriter(fileOutputPath, false);
        int icolcount = dataSource.Columns.Count;
        if (!firstRowIsColumnHeader)
                {                
        for (int i = 0; i < icolcount; i++)
        {                    
            sw.Write(dataSource.Columns[i]);                  
            if (i < icolcount - 1)
                            sw.Write(seperator); 
        }                
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine); 
      }
      public static void WriteToFile(DataTable dataSource, string fileOutputPath)
      {
         WriteToFile(dataSource, fileOutputPath, false, ";");
      }
      public static void WriteToFile(DataTable dataSource, string fileOutputPath, bool firstRowIsColumnHeader)
      {
         WriteToFile(dataSource, fileOutputPath, firstRowIsColumnHeader, ";");
      }
}
```